# for loop executes wrongly when no file found

Tags: bash, file-extension, for-in-loop

I have this bash "for in" loop that looks for pdf files in a directory and prompt them (simplified for the example)

```
#!/bin/bash
for pic in "$INPUT"/*.pdf
do
    echo "found: ${pic}"
done
```

This script works well when there are pdf files in $INPUT directory, however, when there are no pdf files in the directory, I get :

> found: /home/.../input-folder/*.pdf

Is it the expected behavior ?
How can I deal with it with a for in loop ?
Do I need to use ls or find ?

I tried with and without quotes around "$INPUT". There are no spaces in files names and directory names.

Comment: See [Enumerating files or doing stuff with files](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs#Enumerating_files_or_doing_stuff_with_files).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. According to the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), in the Pathname Expansion section:

> After word splitting, unless the -f option has been set, bash scans each word for the characters *, ?, and [. If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of file names matching the pattern. **If no matching file names are found, and the shell option nullglob is not enabled, the word is left unchanged.**

As a result, if no matches for `"$INPUT"/*.pdf` are found, the loop will be executed on the pattern itself. But in the next sentence of the man page:

> If the nullglob option is set, and no matches are found, the word is removed.

That's what you want! So just do:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for pic in "$INPUT"/*.pdf
do
    echo "found: ${pic}"
done
```

(But be aware that this may change the behavior of other things in unexpected ways. For example, try running `shopt -s nullglob; ls *.unmatchedextension` and see what happens.)

Answer (score 1):

I would just add a file exists test like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if test -e `echo "$INPUT"/*.pdf | cut -d' ' -f1`
then
    for pic in "$INPUT"/*.pdf
    do
        echo "found: ${pic}"
    done
fi
```

Comment: The `test` command will probably fail if `"$INPUT"/*.pdf` matches more than one files (too many arguments).

Comment: You're right - answer corrected

Comment: Closer, but the `test` could still fail if the first file name produced contains a space; `cut` will output a partial path, not the entire path.